# SQL Query to split 2 columns x 1 row into 1 column x 2 rows

Tags: mysql

I have summarised a dataset using the following code:

```sql
SELECT sum(Money1_legalA), sum(Money2_damageB ), count(*) as Count
FROM y;
```

The resulting table is:

| Money1_legalA | Money2_damageB | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 9 | 7 |

I would like to condense the two Money fields so the resulting table looks like this:

| Group | Money | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Legal | 10 | 7 |
| Damage | 9 | 7 |

How would I go about adjusting the existing code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'Legal' as `Group`, sum(Money1_legalA) as Money, count(*) as Count FROM y
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Damage', sum(Money2_damageB), count(*) FROM y
```